# Deps file in a Repo consisting C++ and Open Source Code, what is the use?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand what exactly deps file and where/how it gets referenced in a project while developing software, it contents include a "REPO1" while other sub project("REPO2") includes another deps file ("deps file 2") which consists both "REPO1" and "REPO2" , I apologize if my question borders on being elementary.

Thanks

Comment: "Deps" stands for dependencies. It is most likely for some building environment/script which reads those files and hierarchically builds everything mentioned to satisfy that all dependencies are ready. We can say more if you tell with what command you build your project.

Comment: @AlexGeorg Thanks for the Answer , to build the project command in use is "MAKE INSTALL" which builds relevant SDK including the file system for the PRODUCT board.